# Access individual object's values from an array of objects React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, react-hooks

I'm having a problem trying to access some values of an object inside an array that I receive as a response from an Axios Get method.

I want to have access to values like id, dateTime, sensorData of each object of the array separately, like result[0].id (dateTime, sensorData, etc).

Part of my code:

```html
const ShowSensorsScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [ result, setResult ] = useState([]);
    const id = navigation.getParam('id');

    useEffect(() => {
        getResult(id);
    }, []);

    const getResult = async id => {
        const response = await searchApi.get(`/sensorData/${id}`);
        setResult(response.data);
    };
    
    console.log(result[0]);
    return (
        <ImageBackground source={backgroundImage} style={styles.ImageBackground}>
            <Bar>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
                    {result[0].dateTime}
                </Text>
            </Bar>
            <SensorsDetail  evaluation={result} />
        </ImageBackground>
    );
};
```

Using a console.log(result) or even console.log(result[**index**]) everything runs fine but trying with result[0].id gets an error saying undefined is not an object...

Sample from console.log(result):

```html
Array []
Array [
  Object {
    "sensorData01": "100.00000",
    "sensorData02": "101.00000",
    "sensorData03": "102.00000",
    "sensorData04": "103.00000",
    "dateTime": "2020-01-06T23:10:56Z",
    "id": 1,
    "idEvaluation": 1,
  },
  Object {
    "sensorData01": "110.00000",
    "sensorData02": "111.00000",
    "sensorData03": "112.00000",
    "sensorData04": "113.00000",
    "dateTime": "2020-01-06T23:11:16Z",
    "id": 2,
    "idEvaluation": 1,
  },
]
```

And from console.log(result[0]):

```html
undefined
Object {
  "dadosSensor01": "100.00000",
  "dadosSensor02": "101.00000",
  "dadosSensor03": "102.00000",
  "dadosSensor04": "103.00000",
  "dataHora": "2020-01-06T23:10:56Z",
  "id": 1,
  "idAvaliacao": 1,
}
```

I would thank any sort of help I can get on this!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `setResult` (hooks) is async and you are printing `result.data` before the state is set. Try the below to print once you have set the correct data in result.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(result[0]);
  }, [result]);

const searchApi = async (searchAppointment) => {
       console.log('Searching appointment...');
       setIsLoading(true);
       try {
               const response = await baseURL.get(
                   `/sensorsData/${searchAppointment}`);
           console.log(response.data[0]);
           setResult(response.data);
           console.log(result[0])
       } catch (err) {
           console.log(err);
           setErrorMessage('Something went wrong, please try again later...');
       }
       setIsLoading(false);
   };
```

Please refer this for useState callbacks - [useState callbacks](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usestate-callback)

Comment: Hello! thank you for your support, you were right, updated the code on the post.

But still I can't access individual values of the objects like result[0].id etc...
How can I do this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understood what you mean, I still can't access the individual values like result[0].id or etc, only the whole object like result[0], result[1] and so on...

Comment: what is ur console.log(result[0]) is printing?

Comment: I'm sorry, having trouble to give the proper formatting on comment here, first I get an ***undefined***
then I get an Object like this:

***Object {
  "sensorData01": "100.00000",
  "sensorData02": "101.00000",
  "sensorData03": "102.00000",
  "sensorData04": "103.00000",
  "dateTime": "2020-01-06T23:10:56Z",
  "id": 1,
  "idEvaluation": 1,
}***

Comment: When are you getting undefined? I mean where do you put that console.log?

Comment: I get it as soon as I press to search on the Api, before receiving the result I think;
It happens just the same wherever I place the console.log, even on an useEffect with the [result] as you showed me.

Answer (score 0):

So I've got help from another post and it turns out that to do what I needed I had to use **.map()** and it got like this:

```html
    const sensor01 = avaliacao.map((item) => item.dadosSensor01);
    const sensor02 = avaliacao.map((item) => item.dadosSensor02);
    const sensor03 = avaliacao.map((item) => item.dadosSensor03);
    const sensor04 = avaliacao.map((item) => item.dadosSensor04);
```

If anyone has any better other way I would love to hear it, for now, I thank you all for the amazing support!